# Auto-managed docker-compose volume not shared among containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, volume

I have a bit of hard time understanding the way `docker-compose` handles auto-managed volumes. Here is an example `docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  one:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c 'echo one >> /data/db.txt && cat /data/db.txt | wc -l'
    volumes:
      - /data
```

And here is what I get (`docker-compose` logs stripped out)

```bash
$ docker-compose up
1 # as expected

$ docker-compose start
$ docker-compose up
3 # as expected

$ docker-compose run one
1 # why ? I expected 4
```

So it seems the volume is not shared between containers of the same service (in this example, the service `one`). Actually a new volume seems to be created every time `run` is used

```bash
test $(docker volume ls | wc -l) -eq 0 # ensure clean env

repeat 10 docker-compose up
test $(docker volume ls | wc -l) -eq 1 # works

docker-compose down && docker volume prune -f # cleanup

repeat 10 docker-compose run one
test $(docker volume ls | wc -l) -eq 1 # fails, result is 10 instead
```

[The `docker-compose` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) does not really help, the only explanation seems to be

> Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
>
> ```yml
> volumes:
>   - /var/lib/mysql
> ```

I do not encounter this issue when using named volumes (*e.g.* `data:/data`). So **why is a new volume created for new containers of the same service ?** And what is the point of such behavior to be the default ?

*N.B. I know I should use explicitly defined volumes instead, but I want to understand the default behavior, and why it is this way*

> `docker` and `docker-compose` version info https://pastebin.com/8TuFCg2i

Answer (score 1):

Define the volume in the following way

```yaml
volumes:
  - ${local_path}:/data
```

or using docker volumes

```yaml
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  db-data:

services:
  one:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c 'echo one >> /data/db.txt && cat /data/db.txt | wc -l'
    volumes:
      - db-data:/data
```